# How to force write (`:w!`) and quit (`:q`) vim in the same command?

Tags: vim

How can I force write (`:w!`) and quit (`:q`) vim in the same command? I try `:w!q` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Note that there's a [whole stackexchange site dedicated to vi and vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer you can use command like:

```
:wq!
```

But you can simplify the command by enter:

```
:x!
```

(`x=wq` in this case)

Maybe you can consider reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828573/2908599) in StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

The `vim` idiom is `:wq!`. Another read of `man vim` is indicated.

Comment: I suggest you read `man vim` yourself — nowhere does it explain `:wq!`.

Comment: Yes, `:h :w` or `:h write-quit` within `vim` may be more indicated. See also `:xa!` to only save the modified buffers and `a`ll of them, unconditionally (`!`).